# MongoDB objectId references

Tags: mongodb

I have one collection, with the id of the documents set as MongoDb Object Ids (so appear in the db as:

```
Collection1

    "someId": {
        "$oid": "5003cb802e28076412000001"
    },
```

In another collection, I am referencing these.  However sometimes these references appear to be stored as proper oids:

```
Collection 2

    "someForiegnId": {
        "$oid": "5003cb802e28076412000001"
    },
```

But other times they have made it into the db as a normal string.

```
Collection 2    

    "someForiegnId": "5003cb802e28076412000001",
```

My question is - **Is is important to store these foreign references in the oid format, or can they just be strings?**

Comment: Make it either string or object id, but not both. I'd probably choose strings.

Comment: Yeah, I'm rationalising the code now, but wanted to know which to go for.

Comment: strings can be easier to work with, but are also twice the size on disk.

Comment: @JohnnyHK - do you know if there are performance benefits too? (if you indexed this field/queried on it) - or is it just a space optimisation?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I would expect that performance would be similar.

Comment: ObjectId performance will be better. Both do a binary compare but an ObjectId is significantly less data than a string representing an ObjectId. That said whether or not the difference is significant enough to make it a real issue depends on the size of your dataset. I would assume the difference in performance is small but memory consumption will be higher (which in turn will result in degraded performance). Long story short; use ObjectId if it's an ObjectId.

Comment: I agree with @RemonvanVliet ObjectId reference is much better for space and querying, a pure string could use up more RAM and resources to query on. I always use ObjectIds for references to other rows, it is smaller and faster than DBRef and string.

Comment: Also I have found that actually ObjectIds are easier to query with than strings

Answer (score 4):

I know that I am answering a 1 year old question, but still.

It is always desirable to be consistent in your database. No matter how you store your data (for example of IP address as a string `"87.123.12.12"` an array `[87, 123, 12, 12]` or a number `1467681804`) it should be always the same way. The same with your data: you have to select one format and stick with it.

The format you will select have implications on how much storage will you use and how fast you will be able to query the data. And the best way is to store them as ObjectID for the following reasons:

- it takes only 12 bytes to store [objectID](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) whereas it will take you twice to store the same in the string. For sure this is a small difference, but it goes absolutely for free. Moreover in the world where you try to fit all your data in memory (or at least as much as possible) this is a good consideration. So you save not only HDD but RAM as well
- you can easily get timestamp from your ID. Sometimes it might be useful to get when the object was created. With strings you can not do this
- if you will decide to create an index based on this field - the size of it will be much smaller and you will query it much faster (because this is a number) then querying by a string.

So even if I would have only string representations - I would change to ObjectID(), in your case this is definitely worth switching (I know that you most probably have already done so).

P.S. You can modify the field by [modifying the query in the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19824993/1090562).

Comment: Do you have any reference for querying object id being much faster?