# Query time in MongoDB taking long time?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB, I have started using it since I have a requirement where there are around 300 Million documents and have to perform some queries on them. So I have created a collection where the structure resembles:

LogsCollection:

```
{  LogID, LogName, Version, Serial, Year, Month, Day, Feature { FeatureID, Name, Hour, Minute, second, millisecond  }}
```

I have inserted 300 Million documents into the collection using C# drvier. So each document is a BSONDocument type.

Now I am trying to query the number of documents with the **Year - 2012**. The query time is **more than 15 mins**. Is this the expected behavior for the 300 Million documents I have inserted or Is mongoDB expected to give better performance?

I am also doubting whether the structure I have created in the collection is correct. Can anyone guide me with this?

The queries are basically based on the Date or time and FeatureID.

Comment: You should create an index on year if you want to run queries on it. Like `db.logs.ensureIndex({'Year': 1})`.

Comment: Could you provide output from `explain`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. My queries may be on different parameters like-**Year, month, day, and even on FeatureID / Name**. So having Index on One field like **Year** might help? The queries may also be based on 2 or 3 fields. It changes each time. So how should the indexing be done?

Comment: did you find an answer for that?

Answer (score 4):

For sure this is not an expected behavior.

I would recommend to do some changes: because you are new to mongodb I assume that you do not have indexes on your documents, and therefore it makes a full scan (check every document). It is a good practice to have indexes on the keys you are going to do frequent search. So do the following:

```
db.logs.ensureIndex({'Year': 1})
db.logs.ensureIndex({'FeatureID': 1})
```

Another thing, I would recommend to convert this date/time keys into [Date()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/) fields and then perform [time range queries](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/).

But at the beginning just try to make an index and see the performance. Do not forget about [explain](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) operator to understand what mongodb is doing behind the hood.

**P.S.** after your commend about querying on different time options, I would actually suggest to convert to mongo date. You can look at my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19824993/1090562) how to do something like this (surely you need to modify it to make what you want, but the idea is the same).

Comment: @ Salvador Dali:I did create Index on the Date column and did convert the date/time keys to Date() field.I have used the C# driver to create the BsonDocument and insert it into Logs collection.Logs collection has the following fields:  LogID, LogName, Version, Serial, Date, FeatureID, FeatureName. There are 30,00,00,000 records in the log table. After indexing also, the time taken for this query is more than an hour- **var start= new Date(2010,1,1); var end=new Date(2011,1,1); db.LogsTable.find({DateTime:{$gte:start, $lt:end}}).count()**.Can anyone let me know whats wrong with the collection?

Comment: @user2439903 it is hard to tell what is wrong here. I would suggest you to create a new question where you would include explain for your query. This would give some information what is wrong