# How to fetch records without case sensitive in MongoDb?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection like

```
{

"email" : "sh@Gmail.com"

}
```

My query should be like , it has to find matching email irrespective of case whether its capital or small but it should match exactly.

In sql we will do like `where Lower(strEmail) = Lower(@emailParameterPassed) to satisfy this same.`

**UPDATE**

I got it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863399/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-make-a-case-insensitive-query).
Thanks

How to achieve this in mongoDb?

I am using c# native driver with mongoDb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nonetheless the answer you are duplicating will give you a correct result, it is not a good idea to do queries like this. Why should you use regex (without indexes ) if you can use normal equal and take advantage of indexes?

There is no difference between `sh@Gmail.com` and `sh@gmail.com` so why not to store them in a canonical form in the first place and then to use normal search. To change all the documents, you can refer to my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19824993/1090562).