# How to optimise this mongodb query in C#?

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, query-optimization

```
SELECT 
Member_strMobileNo,
strMembername
FROM tblMembers WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE CHARINDEX (LOWER(@strMembername), LOWER(strMembername)) > 0
OR CHARINDEX (LOWER(@strMobileNo), LOWER(Member_strMobileNo)) > 0
```

This is my SQL query I want to fetch data from MongoDB using C# driver ..
My Json Structure is :

```
{
 "memberName" : "seema",
 "Email" : seema@gmail.com
  "Mob"  : 9876543
}
```

Actually this query is used fro searching details.

In mongo i tried this ,

```
 var query = Query.Or(Query.In("memberName",  BsonRegularExpression.Create(String.Format("/{0}/i", strMemberName)) ),
                                     new QueryDocument("Mob", BsonRegularExpression.Create(String.Format("/{0}/i", strMobileNo))).
```

But i guess this query will not be fine since because of resource expensive BsonRegularExpression.Check this [this answer in that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845759/how-to-fetch-records-without-case-sensitive-in-mongodb/19846140#19846140).

I am using c#, mongoDb, mongodb C# native driver.

How to optimise this..
I am new to mongoDb..
Thanks for all replies..

Comment: Don't use regexes, simply normalize the string to a consistent casing in the same way you're doing it in SQL.

Comment: This seems like a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: mnemosyn, sorry I did not Get this

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an aggregate, project $toLower See: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/

Something like: 
db.posts.aggregate([{$project:{date2:"$date",title:{$toLower:"$title"}}}

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do it efficiently with MongoDB.

I suggest you maintain a lower case version of your fields (eg. normalizedMemberName), have them indexed and use them for your queries.