# How to deal with 'undefined' fields in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

The values of some fields became 'undefined' after I did an operation on the collection.
It's like:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "mia",
  country: undefined,
  birthday: undefined
}
```

I want to update the country and birthday fields to "Not known" if the values of them are undefined, for all the document in this collection. How to do it?

Comment: Write a loop in the console to process each document and do the operation you want.

Comment: how did you examine the documents? is the above output from the mongo shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be interesting to know what have you done so that the fields became `undefined`? Whenever I was trying to achieve `undefined` I ended up with `null`.

Another thing: also I understand why you need to change from `undefined`. You can not search by `undefined` in console. But I would change them to `null`, not to "Not known" (assuming you do not have a specific thing that match `null`). Another thing is just to remove the fields at all.

In any case, to do what you want you have to [iterate through all documents and update them the way you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19824993/1090562)