# How to update array of primitive types in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Collection:

```
post:
  title: 'Help'
  tags: ['mongodb','foo']
```

Elements of the `tags` array are unique. I want to change all `foo` tags in the collection to `bar` tags. Can I `$set` an element inside an array in one step, or do I have to remove the `foo`s from all tags arrays and add `bar`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
db.posts.update({ tags: "foo" }, { $set: { "tags.$": "bar" } }, { multi: true});
```

But if your `tags` array contains more than one `foo` value, this query will replace **only one** of them.

Comment: So to achieve what OP needs he need to run N+1 commands against the server if the number of elements is N

Comment: Yes, it's true, if there are N `foo` values in one `tags` array. But as far as I understand, OP wants to update all collection of posts rather than certain array.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this at the moment with one query. One reasonable way to achieve this would have been to use $pull and $push like this:

```
db.a.update({
    tags : 'foo'
  },{
    $pull : {tags : 'foo'},
    $push : {tags : 'bar'}
  },{
    multi : true
})
```

But this would end up with **Field name duplication not allowed with modifiers** error message which is basically tells you that you can not use $pull and $push at the same time. [Jira ticket was filed](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1050) few years ago, but still it is unresolved (and based on **Minor** label here it is highly unlikely to be resolved soon).

One way to go with it is to run a query to find IDs of the documents that has `foo`, then another query to remove all these `foo` and another one to insert `bars` for all IDs. I know that potentially in between of these updates something can modify the collection, but this is one option.

Another way is to iterate through all the elements which has tags as foo and to [modify them in foreach statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19824993/1090562).